# Facebook Graph API photo upload fails after V2.4 is deprecated

Tags: jsp, facebook-graph-api

This code has been working for years - it uploads a photo to a group I manage.  At the same time Facebook Graph API v 2.4 was deprecated (early October), it stopped working.  The very last line throws an exception, which I catch:

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/photos

The access token is good, since I use it to post text messages, and that still works fine.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

```
    //-------Facebook Graph API stuff-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // here is the ID of the page
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/photos";
    String accesstoken = "iremovedtherealone";

    // this is the file on the server, after the upload - use forward slashes /
    File binaryFile = new File(savePathFile);

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.
    String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.

    URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true); // true = autoFlush, important!

        // Send access token
        writer.write("--" + boundary);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"access_token\"");
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write(accesstoken);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.flush();

        // Send message
        writer.write("--" + boundary);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"");
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write(strTweet);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.flush();

        // Send binary file
        writer.write("--" + boundary);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"; filename=\"" + binaryFile.getName() + "\"");
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(binaryFile.getName()));
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.flush();

        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(binaryFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            output.flush(); // Important! Output cannot be closed. Close of writer will close output as well.
        } 
        finally {
            if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) { strReturn = "IOException: " + logOrIgnore.toString();}
        }
        writer.write(CRLF);
        writer.flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of binary boundary.

        // End of multipart/form-data.
        writer.write("--" + boundary + "--");
        writer.write(CRLF);
    } 
    finally {
        if (writer != null) writer.close();
    }               

    // this triggers it
    InputStream graphResponse = connection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Start by checking the response body, it usually contains a human-readable error message.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm not sure how to get the response body.  The last line, connection.getInputStream() causes an exception and the exception message is the 400 response.  How am I able to look at the response?  thx